# How to Install Numpy in PyPy on Windows

Tags: python, numpy, pip, pypy

I want to install Numpy on PyPy on windows but I cannot.
Here is my errors:

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'C:\pypy3.7-v7.3.4-win64\pypy3.exe' 'C:\pypy3.7-v7.3.4-win64\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py' prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel 'C:\Users\mypc\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp2y257dmz'
         cwd: C:\Users\mypc\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-mnjup8qy\numpy_43041314b31a4b2fa25b7000b140e261
    Complete output (189 lines):
    Processing numpy/random\_bounded_integers.pxd.in
    Processing numpy/random\bit_generator.pyx
    Processing numpy/random\mtrand.pyx
    Processing numpy/random\_bounded_integers.pyx.in
    Processing numpy/random\_common.pyx
    Processing numpy/random\_generator.pyx
    Processing numpy/random\_mt19937.pyx
    Processing numpy/random\_pcg64.pyx
    Processing numpy/random\_philox.pyx
    Processing numpy/random\_sfc64.pyx
    Cythonizing sources
    blas_opt_info:
    blas_mkl_info:
    No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
    customize MSVCCompiler
      libraries mkl_rt not found in ['C:\\', 'C:\\pypy3.7-v7.3.4-win64\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    blis_info:
      libraries blis not found in ['C:\\', 'C:\\pypy3.7-v7.3.4-win64\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    openblas_info:
      libraries openblas not found in ['C:\\', 'C:\\pypy3.7-v7.3.4-win64\\libs']
    get_default_fcompiler: matching types: '['gnu', 'intelv', 'absoft', 'compaqv', 'intelev', 'gnu95', 'g95', 'intelvem', 'intelem', 'flang']'
    customize GnuFCompiler
    Could not locate executable g77
    Could not locate executable f77
    customize IntelVisualFCompiler
    Could not locate executable ifort
    Could not locate executable ifl
    customize AbsoftFCompiler
    Could not locate executable f90
    customize CompaqVisualFCompiler
    Could not locate executable DF
    customize IntelItaniumVisualFCompiler
    Could not locate executable efl
    customize Gnu95FCompiler
    Could not locate executable gfortran
    Could not locate executable f95
    customize G95FCompiler
    Could not locate executable g95
    customize IntelEM64VisualFCompiler
    customize IntelEM64TFCompiler
    Could not locate executable efort
    Could not locate executable efc
    customize PGroupFlangCompiler
    Could not locate executable flang
    don't know how to compile Fortran code on platform 'nt'
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_3_10_blas_threads_info:
    Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
      libraries tatlas not found in ['C:\\', 'C:\\pypy3.7-v7.3.4-win64\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_3_10_blas_info:
      libraries satlas not found in ['C:\\', 'C:\\pypy3.7-v7.3.4-win64\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_blas_threads_info:
    Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
      libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in ['C:\\', 'C:\\pypy3.7-v7.3.4-win64\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_blas_info:
      libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in ['C:\\', 'C:\\pypy3.7-v7.3.4-win64\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    blas_info:
      libraries blas not found in ['C:\\', 'C:\\pypy3.7-v7.3.4-win64\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    blas_src_info:
      NOT AVAILABLE

      NOT AVAILABLE

    non-existing path in 'numpy\\distutils': 'site.cfg'
    lapack_opt_info:
    lapack_mkl_info:
      libraries mkl_rt not found in ['C:\\', 'C:\\pypy3.7-v7.3.4-win64\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    openblas_lapack_info:
      libraries openblas not found in ['C:\\', 'C:\\pypy3.7-v7.3.4-win64\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    openblas_clapack_info:
      libraries openblas,lapack not found in ['C:\\', 'C:\\pypy3.7-v7.3.4-win64\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    flame_info:
      libraries flame not found in ['C:\\', 'C:\\pypy3.7-v7.3.4-win64\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_3_10_threads_info:
    Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
      libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in C:\
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\pypy3.7-v7.3.4-win64\libs
      libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in C:\pypy3.7-v7.3.4-win64\libs
    <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_threads_info'>
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_3_10_info:
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
      libraries satlas,satlas not found in C:\
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\pypy3.7-v7.3.4-win64\libs
      libraries satlas,satlas not found in C:\pypy3.7-v7.3.4-win64\libs
    <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_info'>
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_threads_info:
    Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
      libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in C:\
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\pypy3.7-v7.3.4-win64\libs
      libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in C:\pypy3.7-v7.3.4-win64\libs
    <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_threads_info'>
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_info:
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
      libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in C:\
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\pypy3.7-v7.3.4-win64\libs
      libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in C:\pypy3.7-v7.3.4-win64\libs
    <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_info'>
      NOT AVAILABLE

    lapack_info:
      libraries lapack not found in ['C:\\', 'C:\\pypy3.7-v7.3.4-win64\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    lapack_src_info:
      NOT AVAILABLE

      NOT AVAILABLE

    numpy_linalg_lapack_lite:
      FOUND:
        language = c
        define_macros = [('HAVE_BLAS_ILP64', None), ('BLAS_SYMBOL_SUFFIX', '64_')]

    running dist_info
    running build_src
    build_src
    building py_modules sources
    creating build
    creating build\src.win-amd64-3.7
    creating build\src.win-amd64-3.7\numpy
    creating build\src.win-amd64-3.7\numpy\distutils
    building library "npymath" sources
    Running from numpy source directory.
    setup.py:485: UserWarning: Unrecognized setuptools command, proceeding with generating Cython sources and expanding templates
      run_build = parse_setuppy_commands()
    C:\Users\mypc\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-mnjup8qy\numpy_43041314b31a4b2fa25b7000b140e261\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1989: UserWarning:
        Optimized (vendor) Blas libraries are not found.
        Falls back to netlib Blas library which has worse performance.
        A better performance should be easily gained by switching
        Blas library.
      if self._calc_info(blas):
    C:\Users\mypc\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-mnjup8qy\numpy_43041314b31a4b2fa25b7000b140e261\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1989: UserWarning:
        Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) libraries not found.
        Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas]) or by setting
        the BLAS environment variable.
      if self._calc_info(blas):
    C:\Users\mypc\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-mnjup8qy\numpy_43041314b31a4b2fa25b7000b140e261\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1989: UserWarning:
        Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) sources not found.
        Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas_src]) or by setting
        the BLAS_SRC environment variable.
      if self._calc_info(blas):
    C:\Users\mypc\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-mnjup8qy\numpy_43041314b31a4b2fa25b7000b140e261\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1849: UserWarning:
        Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) libraries not found.
        Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack]) or by setting
        the LAPACK environment variable.
      return getattr(self, '_calc_info_{}'.format(name))()
    C:\Users\mypc\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-mnjup8qy\numpy_43041314b31a4b2fa25b7000b140e261\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1849: UserWarning:
        Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) sources not found.
        Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack_src]) or by setting
        the LAPACK_SRC environment variable.
      return getattr(self, '_calc_info_{}'.format(name))()
    C:\pypy3.7-v7.3.4-win64\lib-python\3\distutils\dist.py:274: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'define_macros'
      warnings.warn(msg)
    error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Build Tools for Visual Studio": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/
    ----------------------------------------
WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/82/a8/1e0f86ae3f13f7ce260e9f782764c16559917f24382c74edfb52149897de/numpy-1.20.2.zip#sha256=878922bf5ad7550aa044aa9301d417e2d3ae50f0f577de92051d739ac6096cee (from https://pypi.org/simple/numpy/) (requires-python:>=3.7). Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\pypy3.7-v7.3.4-win64\pypy3.exe' 'C:\pypy3.7-v7.3.4-win64\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py' prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel 'C:\Users\mypc\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp2y257dmz' Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: that comes after `pip install numpy`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have any compiler on your system, so PyPy can't compile the packages.

notice the line `error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Build Tools for Visual Studio": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/`

Download the compiler with default settings and try again.

Comment: I have another issue in installing pandas

Comment: @SaeedZali open a new question for that. Don't forget to post everything including stack trace and what you did to allow people to help you.

Answer (score 3):

PyPy release manager here.

I would strongly advise waiting for the 7.3.5 release (soon) and probably even then waiting until there are binary packages available on conda (in a little while). It seems the windows support is not quite ready for general consumption yet.

In any case, if speed is what interests you: PyPy will not be faster for most tasks targeting pandas and numpy until the HPy versions come out, sometime far in the future.